# Stopping the user from entering or selecting future date

Tags: asp.net

Would anyone have any thoughts about stopping the user from selecting or entering any future dates. The AJAX regular expression validator I had only verify the date if it is in DD//MM/YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a lot of options, it depends on your app. I guess you allow user to type anything, that makes it harder b/c you have to determine if its a valid date first. If you have a valid date, just compare it to the current date, you could do it onblur for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a compare validator instead of a reg ex validator.  It allows you to specify a data type, a comparison value, and a comparison operation (less than in your case).

If you want to specify a minimum date as well then check out the range validator.

If you have some other reason that you must use the reg ex validator then you are likely moving into the realm of some custom javascript.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion, RangeValidator did the trick for me. Here is the code snippet that solve my problem.

Comment: <asp:RangeValidator    ID="RangeValidator1"
                                        runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtDOB"
                                        ErrorMessage="Invalid"
                                        Type="Date" Display="Dynamic" />
            RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = new DateTime(1600, 01, 01).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");